# Measure of improvement in pre and post survey.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I did a survey to measure students perceived understanding of several topic at the beginning of the semester and few weeks later. The surveys are done anonymously and I cannot match the pre and post responses. I want to measure how much their understanding has improved.
Here is a sample data:

```
   survey                 question          response count    percent
 1 pre        I.understand.methods Strongly Disagree     5 0.05813953
 2 pre        I.understand.methods          Disagree     7 0.08139535
 3 pre        I.understand.methods           Neutral    19 0.22093023
 4 pre        I.understand.methods             Agree    32 0.37209302
 5 pre        I.understand.methods    Strongly Agree    23 0.26744186
 6 post       I.understand.methods Strongly Disagree     0 0.00000000
 7 post       I.understand.methods          Disagree     3 0.12500000
 8 post       I.understand.methods           Neutral     4 0.16666667
 9 post       I.understand.methods             Agree     8 0.33333333
10 post       I.understand.methods    Strongly Agree     9 0.37500000
```

[image: The data is displayed here]

It is safe to assume that the number of pre and post responses will be almost the same. In the data above it is not because I am still waiting on responses from the post survey.

What are possible metrics that I can use?

This question is related to [How do I compare student pre-test scores with post-test scores to evaluate whether or not they "learned"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115524/how-do-i-compare-student-pre-test-scores-with-post-test-scores-to-evaluate-wheth) but different.

Comment: For future studies of this kind, you could ask each student to give info such as mother's and father's birthday and last 2 digits of driving licence number on each survey. That way you could pair (almost) all without compromising confidentiality. // For the current data, I don't immediately see a valid analysis. Indep conditions of chi-sq $2 \times 5$ contingency table (Pre/Post by Opinion) would be not be met. // If graph is for all subjects, I'd hesitate to look for clear conclusion: Disagree and Strongly Agree both increased. // Also, not measuring improvement, but _perception_ of it.

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't gotten any answers here is a solution I found.
I can use the mean rank to measure how the rankings in the pre and post differ. The mean rank can be calculated from the data. For the first survey:
$$
(5*1 + 7*2 + 19*3 + 32*4 + 23 * 5) / (5 + 7 + 19 + 32 + 23) = 3.71
$$

For the second survey:
$$
(0*1 + 3*2 + 4*3 + 8*4 + 9*5) / (0 + 3 + 4 + 8 + 9) = 3.96
$$

So, I can conclude that the ranking has improved by $3.96 - 3.71 = 0.25$